# GORM (varchar .save(), non DATE): ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Tags: grails-orm

Hello I'm receiving a very strange error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string.  All my internet searching has related to DATE issues.  Mine is just to save a simple string.  If you see the issue please let me know how to fix it.

Column of issue

```
TREND: VARCHAR2(31, CHAR), no constraints
```

Mapped in GORM by:

```
String trend
...
static constraints = {
    trend(nullable: true, blank: true)
... } ...
static mapping = {
    trend column: "TREND", sqlType: "varchar(31)"
...}
```

Issue method:

```
    def fix_trend(){
    // There should ever only be three values found in the trend column
    //  of the Reports table: "TRENDING UP", "TRENDING STEADY", "TRENDING DOWN"
    println "Running groovy database procedure : fix_trend"
    StatusReport.list().each{
        String trend = it.trend
        if (trend != 'TRENDING UP' && trend != 'TRENDING STEADY' && trend != 'TRENDING DOWN'){
            trend = trend?.toUpperCase()
            if (trend == null){
                trend = 'TRENDING STEADY'
            }
            else if (trend.contains('UP')){
                trend = 'TRENDING UP';
            }
            else if (trend.contains('DOWN')){
                trend = 'TRENDING DOWN';
            }
            else{
                trend = 'TRENDING STEADY';
            }
            it.trend = trend;
            it.save();
        }
    }
    println "fix_trend completed"
}
```

The purpose of the method is to ensure all the values are either TRENDING UP, TRENDING DOWN, or TRENDING STEADY.

Stacktrace:

```
Running groovy database procedure : fix_trend
fix_trend completed
Error |
2015-01-05 10:53:02,392 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
Error |
2015-01-05 10:53:02,481 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - SQLDataException occurred when processing request: [GET] /investigator/statusReports/selection
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
. Stacktrace follows:
Message: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
    Line | Method
->>  439 | processError         in oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    395 | processError         in     ''
|    802 | processError . . . . in oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall
|    436 | receive              in oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun
|    186 | doRPC . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    521 | doOALL               in oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall
|    205 | doOall8 . . . . . .  in oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement
|   1008 | executeForRows       in     ''
|   1307 | doExecuteWithTimeout in oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement
|   3449 | executeInternal      in oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement
|   3530 | executeUpdate . . .  in     ''
|   1350 | executeUpdate        in oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper
|     16 | selection . . . . .  in investigator.StatusReportsController
|    198 | doFilter             in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . . . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker            in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run                  in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: Make sure that the encoding you are using to insert values is by the database defenition

Comment: My database's NLS_CHARACTERSET property is 'AL32UTF8'.  Is it an encoding error?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own issue.

There was a Date field in the table that was misrepresented as a String in the Domain class.  Even though I was trying to update a VARCHAR2 field the domain_class.save() method updates every attribute of that domain_class-- thus the error was not associated with the TREND field but the misrepresented DATE field.

I figured this out by adding to DataSource.groovy

```
logSql = true
formatSql = true
```

and Config.groovy

```
log4j.main = {
trace 'org.hibernate.type'
debug 'org.hibernate.SQL'
...
```

This showed that the update statement generated by .save() tries to update EVERY attribute.

Hope this helps someone in the future.